# Angular 2 select complex object with initial value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

In Angular (2.2) I'm trying to initialize a `select` using a complex object.  But since the object isn't an actual reference to something in `select` list (even though it's identical), it doesn't recognize it as selected.   Here's what I'm working with:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.object">
  <option *ngFor="let obj of objects" [ngValue]="obj">{{ obj.name }}</option>
</select>
```

This works as intended when you change the selection.  But on initial load, even if `model.object` is identical to an object in the list, it doesn't select anything.

The two workarounds for this are to (1) run through the list and swap `model.object` to be a direct reference, but this is one row in a table of many items like this, so that's going to be very expensive.  Or (2) bind `[(ngModel)]="model.object.id"` and `[ngValue]="object.id"` (a simple type), but I really want the whole object to be represented in the model, so I'd still have to bind to the event handler, run through the array of items until I find that id, and set it myself.

I was hoping there was a way to do a `track by` of sorts, so the initial selection tracks by id.

In Angular 1, this could be achieved by:

```
<select ng-model="model.object"
    ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in objects">
```

but I can't seem to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Angular
  <select (change)="chnageProduct($event.currentTarget.value)" >
  <option *ngFor="let obj of objects" [value]="obj"
   [selected]="model.name === obj.name"
   >{{ obj.name }}</option>
</select>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  result: any = {};

  constructor(){
  }

  model =  {name : "1"}


  objects = [{name : "1"},{name: "2"}]

  chnageProduct(val){
     this.model = val;
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HN8VFv4rzik7nDTrCntO?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Cool, I guess I'll have to go with this. It's too bad we can't use the native `ngModel` anymore though.  This seems like a common scenario / oversight on their part.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonG Guess what?! They've noticed ;) Custom comparator function as a parameter is on its way https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268

Comment: This does not work at all. I have just ran the plunker and it setting the string "[object Object]" in the component's model. Not an object. Did this work previously?

Comment: doesn't seem to work, `val` is `"[object Object]"` string literal

Comment: @AnandRockzz, did you check the plunker?

Comment: it appears that $event.currentTarget is null and so you can not retrieve the value in this manner. Is this a recent "problem"?

Comment: exploring $event.target options... the value of each option is string literal "[object Object]"

Comment: a workaround... i passed $event.target instead of $event.currentTarget.value.  Then i looped through options and checked for selected = true and handled from there.

Comment: Hey guys! What do you think about my workaround?
`const value = this.values[Array.from($event.target.querySelectorAll('option')).findIndex(e => (<HTMLOptionElement>e).selected)];` jk jk.